# Xamarin Using API to Insert Data

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, security, xamarin.forms

I have an ASP.net Web API that inserts data from the user after they purchase a product in a Xamarin Application I am currently developing. However, data can also be inserted by simply calling the URL on a web browser from a desktop computer, such as:

```
http://www.mywebapi.com/myfunc?username=bob&prod_enabled=true
```

I only want data inserted AFTER the product has been purchased in my app. In the C# code for the web API, I have:

```
public IActionResult myfunc(string username, string prod_enabled)
{
      // Assume credentials to connect to database are validated
      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                "INSERT INTO users (username, product_enabled) " +
                "VALUES('" + username + "', '" + prod_enabled + "')", connection);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();

                if (i == 1)
                    return Content("True");

                return Content("False");
            } 
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                connection.Close();
                return Content("False");
            }
        }
}
```

My guess is to include a 3rd parameter that validates some sort of token from the Xamarin app, is that correct? I really want to ensure that people don't use the API to fake product purchases. There needs to be some means of verification.

Thanks!

Comment: "after they purchase a product" - what does this mean?  How do they purchase something?  Through your API?  Via the OS in-app purchase?  There is a LOT or missing information here.

Comment: They would purchase the product in the Xamarin app using either Stripe payment or PayPal. The API is simply meant to write to the database only. I followed a PayPal tutorial, and it was simple to implement, but I hadn't noticed anything that can secure the product buy.

Comment: I assume that those payment platforms have some mechanism to validate a transaction.  But without knowing the details I can't make any specific suggestions.  You need to spend some more time researching this

Answer (score 0):

Do you have API? In method of controller add attribute [Authorize]. Or add parametr of user(he buys or he doesn`t buy your application). After validate user use insert data in DB

Comment: I haven't tried using [Authorize] for this particular project just yet. Only for some introduction tutorial that I've done in the past. When I used it, it asked for a username and password. But how would I use that to enable a product when a successful purchase has been made? I plan on using Stripe and PayPal, by the way.

Comment: 1. username and password. It`s not good, 2. phone number and confirm phone by sms. When man buy application - he is concat application to phone number. See identity server

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this way for some reason.

1. It's not correct API Format.See [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/22-best-practices-to-take-your-api-design-skills-to-the-next-level-65569b200b9)
2. Use parameterized queries, ORM, or stored procedures for prevent sql injection[enter link description here](https://www.ptsecurity.com/ww-en/analytics/knowledge-base/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-attacks/)
3. Create Repository Layer then call your command or query form here

Comment: although these are useful comments, none of them actually address the question he asked

Comment: thank you @Jason,but her question not clarity

Comment: Thanks for the links! However, I am now thinking about processing the payment in the API itself. Something I should have mentioned is my database is on Azure. I am assuming they have some sort of payment collection services that's quite secure.